# how to transfer 100 gb data over the network every night at a high speed?

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, spring-batch

There is an external database which we have access to 7 views. Every morning we want to pull all the records from those views. It appears the record is around 100GB. I have tried to use spring batch but it takes almost 15 hours to pull that size of the record. I am looking for a solution where I can do two things 1. speed up this process which will take 1 or 2 hours max and if there network failure then email to a stakeholders about the failures. We need the data both in Elasticsearch as well as MS SQL server.

Following things I have tried

1. Apache Kafka with JDBC Source connector: dint work because the view does not have primary key column neither it has a timestamp column
2. Tried with spring batch JdbcItemReader and RepositoryItemwriter but it's pretty slow. (MS SQL Server to MS SQL Server)
3. Tried with SpringBatch JdbcItemReader and KafkaItemWriter, Kafka consumer to Elasticsearch bulk index. this is the fastest which takes around 15 hours. Chunk size 10k or chunk size 5k both take around the same amount of time.  What are my options?
4. Tried to use Debezium source connector for Kafka ut dint work since the Source db has CDC disabled.

Comment: there are many parameters that can be affecting you, for example, maybe you are being bottlenecked by your network, what's your available bandwidth?

Comment: 58 Mbps download, 82 Mbps upload

Comment: just to clarify, in a perfect world transferring 100GB on a 82mbps conection will take around 3 hours

Comment: What should be the internet speed to make it happen in 3 hours?

Comment: Why do it in batch? You could use Debezium, for example, to stream the events over the course of the day into the destination systems or network (i.e. Kafka), then feed the data to the downstream systems

Comment: we cant use Debezium because the source db is external and we only have access to the view, they (the owner of the source DB) disabled the CDC .